# Value error: Invalid literal for int() with base 10:’’ PYTHON

Tags: python, valueerror

Why do I always get this error for my code: Invalid literal for int() with base 10:’’

I’m trying to make it so that the current player guess is none and I will input a question later.

```
num1 = 10

answer1 = int("")

totalnum = num1 + answer1

answer1 = int(input("enter a number: "))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>
```

Comment: `""` is not a number, hence `int("")` fails. You should remove that line and move the `totalnum` line to the end of your script

Comment: You don't need to initialise variables in that manner in Python. `int('')` tries to cast an empty string to a number.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove the line `answer1 = int("")` from the above code.

```
num1 = 10

answer1 = int(input("enter a number: "))

totalnum = num1 + answer1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert an empty string to an integer, as you are trying to do with `answer1 = int("")`. You can either set answer1 to 0 as a default, or get the input before calculating `totalnum`.

Either:

```
num1 = 10

answer1 = 0

totalnum = num1 + answer1

answer1 = int(input("enter a number: "))
```

or

```
num1 = 10

answer1 = int(input("enter a number: "))

totalnum = num1 + answer1
```